# What reason that land vertebrate evolve keratin while other animal use chitin

Tags: evolution, anatomy

I don't know why there are evolutionary split in material. Why we evolve keratin and lose chitin? What the advantage and disadvantage for each material? Is it because the size or there are other biological reason?

Comment: I think this is too broad a question. Chitin and keratin are completely unrelated -- chitin is a sugar polymer found in exoskeletons and scales, keratin is a protein forming intracellular filaments. They are hardly comparable.

Comment: exoskeletons and cell walls are hard... keratinized skin is more flexy...